# Error is parsing the XML in PHP with simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

My XML to be parsed is in this format:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<env:Header />
<env:Body>
    <n0:ZFM_PAYSLIP1Response xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
        <LS_EMP_PAYSLIP_DATA>
            <ZEMP_NO>00199999</ZEMP_NO>
            <ZEMP_NAME>AJ KUMAR</ZEMP_NAME>
            <ZSAL_MONTH>JUL-2016</ZSAL_MONTH>
            <ZBASIC_PAY>57240.0</ZBASIC_PAY>
            <ZGROSS_PAY>145062.29</ZGROSS_PAY>
            <ZNET_PAY>50728.0</ZNET_PAY>
            <ZINCOME_TAX>25858.0</ZINCOME_TAX>
            <ZLEAVE_ENCASH>0.0</ZLEAVE_ENCASH>
            <ZDUTY_PAY>41976.0</ZDUTY_PAY>
            <ZDA>56950.4</ZDA>
            <ZPERKS>26330.4</ZPERKS>
            <ZHRA>11448.0</ZHRA>
            <ZTOT_DEDUCTIONS>94334.29</ZTOT_DEDUCTIONS>
            <ZCPF>12787.0</ZCPF>
            <ZVPF>50000.0</ZVPF>
            <ZLIC>0.0</ZLIC>
            <ZTHRIFT_FUND>0.0</ZTHRIFT_FUND>
            <ZGRP_INS>160.0</ZGRP_INS>
            <ZPROF_TAX>200.0</ZPROF_TAX>
            <ZDUTY_DAYS>18</ZDUTY_DAYS>
            <ZWEEK_OFF>4</ZWEEK_OFF>
            <ZFL />
            <ZCL />
            <ZEL />
            <ZFPL />
            <ZHPL>8</ZHPL>
            <ZCML />
            <ZEOL />
            <ZUAB />
            <ZDEISGNATION>Sr.Manager(IT)</ZDEISGNATION>
            <ZDEPT_CODE>03007900</ZDEPT_CODE>
            <ZCL_BAL>3</ZCL_BAL>
            <ZEL_BAL>270.5</ZEL_BAL>
            <ZHPL_BAL>180</ZHPL_BAL>
        </LS_EMP_PAYSLIP_DATA>
    </n0:ZFM_PAYSLIP1Response>
</env:Body> </env:Envelope>
```

I am using PHP curl to get data from remote with 
this PHP code :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://hostanme.tld/ERP_PAY_XML.xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
//echo $result;
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
$soap = $xml->children($ns['env']);
echo "<br> len-soap : " . $soap;
$getaddressresponse = $soap->Body->children($ns['n0']);
foreach ($getaddressresponse->getLocationForGroupResponse->children($ns['n0']) as $item)
{
    $item = $item->children();
    echo $item->address . '<br />';
}
?>
```

but still I am not getting any result. Anybody please help..
Is there any other way to parse XML to an object..

Comment: What is `getLocationForGroupResponse`?

Comment: As u_mulder's comment suggests, the nodes you are trying to access don't seem to exist in your sample XML - you are trying to access elements called `<getLocationForGroupResponse>` and `<address>`, which don't even look similar to anything in that XML. Is the example wrong?

Comment: As a tip, it's the namespace identifying URIs you should be hard-coding, not the (possibly random) prefixes like `n0`. You could use something like `define('XMLNS_SOAP', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'); define('XMLNS_SAP_FUNCTIONS', 'urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions');` and then `->children(XMLNS_SOAP)`, etc